# Add value to dictionary key only if it is not already present

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I find that I am often wanting to append values to dictionary lists, but only if the value is not in the list already. Therefore, I'm trying to separate this out into a procedure, and I can't figure out why the following code doesn't achieve this:

```
proc DictAdd {_dictionary key value} {

    upvar 1 $_dictionary dictionary

    if { $value ni [dict get $dictionary $key] } {
        dict lappend dictionary $key $value
    }
}
```

Calling this procedure returns the following error:

```
can't read "dictionary": no such variable
    while executing
"dict get $dictionary $key"
    (procedure "DictAdd" line 5)
    invoked from within
"DictAdd $files baseline $fileName"
    (procedure "getFilesToLoad" line 53)
    invoked from within
...
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the $ before files: DictAdd files baseline $filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the invocation

```
DictAdd $files baseline $fileName
```

`$files` is the *value* of your dictionary, but `DictAdd` expects the *name* of the dictionary variable. If you instead invoke it like this:

```
DictAdd files baseline $fileName
```

the command works as designed.

BTW: if you define `DictAdd` like this:

```
proc DictAdd {_dictionary key value} {
    upvar 1 $_dictionary dictionary

    if {[dict exists $dictionary $key]} {
        dict with dictionary {
            upvar 0 $key values
            if {$value ni $values} {
                lappend values $value
            }
        }
    } else {
        dict lappend dictionary $key $value
    }
}
```

you don't get an error message if the key is missing (it adds the value under that key) (the dictionary still needs to exist outside `DictAdd`) and the checking/adding code gets a little less messy.

Why the name? It’s because of how `upvar` works. The command takes a stack level (in this case 1 = the caller’s level) and a variable name (contained in `_dictionary`; “files” in this case); using those it locates a variable outside the executing command, and creates a local alias inside the executing command (in this case named `dictionary`: `files` outside is now basically the same variable as `dictionary` inside). If you pass something else, e.g. the value of `files`, say `{baseline {a b c}}`, `upvar` will look for a variable called `{baseline {a b c}}` and most likely not find it. It will create the alias anyway, and if you initialize it, a variable called `{baseline {a b c}}` at the caller’s level will actually be created. But, again, you will want to use the name of the variable (of course, the name of the variable could be the value of another variable when you invoke the command…).

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [ni](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) operator, [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This worked perfectly. I'm still trying to figure out why it is that, as you say, the procedure is expecting the name of the dictionary variable rather than its value.

Comment: @BruceJohnson: I added an explanation, let me know if it's not helping.

Comment: @BruceJohnson: and now the explanation is actually added. I seem to have closed the page without saving.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm new to Tcl and your explanation really helped me understand how `upvar` works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the dictionary variable that you are referring to is actually unset, and so impossible to read. Try this:

```
proc DictAdd {_dictionary key value} {
    upvar 1 $_dictionary dictionary
    if {![info exists dictionary]} {
        set dictionary [dict create $key [list $value]]
    } elseif {$value ni [dict get $dictionary $key]} {
        dict lappend dictionary $key $value
    }
}
```